# Need help to understand this chord progression

Tags: theory, guitar, piano, scales, chord-theory

This song should be in a-minor but I'm not sure about key changes in a following passage (starting from f#m7b5 chord). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

am7 / em7 / am7 / em7 / f#m7b5 / B /
em / em/d / c#m7b5 / Gb / Bsus / B / em /

Comment: Thank you for your help! By the way, what you mean about 'off topic'? Is there some rules I'm breaking with my question?

Comment: Yes, there are certain types of questions that are acceptable here and certain that are not, referred to as off topic. Here is a guideline: https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Sometimes you can adjust an off-topic question to make it acceptable. I think you got your answer so you’re good to go!

Comment: Thanks, I need to read rules before posting next time.

Comment: This page is a great resource, welcome and good luck!

Comment: FYI, this *could* be on-topic, since questions about analyzing the theory of a "clearly defined section" of a piece are totally ok. Please edit, though, to make it clear *what* the question is (it's not clear what you're not sure about), and please give more details about the passage. If you have the music notated, please add that; if not, at least the rhythm of the changes.

Comment: I would understand the 'f#m7b5' rather as am6, and the c#m7b5 rather as em6. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think the song is in A minor? The presence of nondiatonic B chord resolving to Em makes me think it's rather E minor. Or at least the section you include is in E minor. It is very characteristic for minor keys that the dominant (V) chord is be major (or dominant seventh chord), rather than minor (Bm would be diatonic in the key of E minor).

• F#ø B Em is iiø-V-I to Em.

• C#ø / Gb / Bsus / B / em  – I would write F# instead of Gb. Then it becomes easier to see that C#ø / F# is iiø-V to B, that is secondary ii and secondary dominant (V). Bsus delays the appearance of the leading tone D#, making us wait longer for the dominant chord, thus increasing the tension. Then finally we have the dominant B (V) resolving to the tonic E (i). This long sequence gravitating towards Em gives me a strong feeling that Em is the tonic, not Am.

I'm not sure on what level you are. If the above explanation is not clear, I would suggest learning about:

- diatonic chords
- ii-V-I progression (sometimes called 251)
- secondary dominants

Comment: Pretty much what I said in comments but more detailed, +1

Comment: Thanks for your thoroughly answer, user1079505